# How to find Lat and long from id of a place from google place API

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have google id of a place,how can I find out that place's Lat and long ?

Is there any google url for that,I want the output in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have all the information you're looking for:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Answer (score 2):

Google Api

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=surat&output=json&key=ABQIAAAAsV7S85DtCo0H9T4zv19FoRTdT40ApbWAnDYRE0-JyP5I6Ha9-xT9G5hCQO5UtOKSH5M3qhp5OXiWaA
```

You can pass place name or zip code.

Comment: In api just replace your place name or zip code with surat(my city name).

Answer (score 1):

I searched for that but could not find it ! You need the **reference** which is given by any kind on search API call ( i.e : radarSearch() ) but I cannot find a link between this reference ( which may vary from call to call ) and the google place ID.